# How to set rootViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rootviewcontroller

I am trying to learn [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321942051) but all the examples are without storyBoard, and when I tried to build the application I caught this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'
```

I tried to fix it with this:

```
ViewController *myView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:myView];
self.window.rootViewController = myView;
```

but then I received another error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HypnoView _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78f68730'
```

Can someone explain to me why is it happening to me?

Comment: `[self.window addSubview:myView];` is not causing any error, or at least a warning? Is `self.window` nil?

Comment: @Larme no, self.window has reference on "myView"

Comment: What is HypnoView?

Comment: Did you deleted `storyboard` which will result in loss of IBOutlet connection of root view

Comment: at the end add `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you cannot add an

```
UIViewController
```

as a subview

The method

```
addSubview:(UIView *)
```

expects a UIview and you are adding a UIViewController.

Secondly adding subview was used in iOS 4 and earlier,
Now you add a view controller as rootviewcontroller.

So simply add,

```
self.window.rootViewController = myView
```

In case you wish to use addSubview, you need to do this

```
[self.window addSubView:myView.view]
```

Answer (score 1):

Goto AppDelegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Property 'myView' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Answer (score 0):

It's done this way. Go to AppDelegate.m and go to - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

```
ViewController *myView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = myView;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

If you want to add an UIView as a subview. Then do the following:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window addSubview:view];
```

Comment: please look https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6uq5szmyccg2jp/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-04%20at%2014.49.31.png?dl=0

Comment: is HypnoView an UIView or UIViewController? You can't set UIView as a rootViewController

Comment: HypoView is UIView. Yes i can't set UIView as a rootViewController

Comment: Then simply make self.window as keywindow and add HypnoView as subview. You can check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-c**

```
@interface AppDelegate () 
    @property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *viewController;
@end


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [self setViewController:[[ViewController alloc] init]];

    [self setWindow:[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]];
    [[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor];
    [[self window] setRootViewController:[self viewController]];
    [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**Swift**

```
var window: UIWindow?
let viewController = ViewController();

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.window!.rootViewController = playerController
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
_window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller];
[self.window setRootViewController:nav];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set:-

in AppDelegate.m file: `_applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions_`

```
UIView *myView;
    self.window.rootViewController = myView

        myView= self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Property 'myView' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6uq5szmyccg2jp/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-04%20at%2014.49.31.png?dl=0

Comment: `rootViewController` is `UIViewController`, not `UIView`. And your code currently does nothing, as you initialize the variable after assigning it.